# how to improve the settimeout?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

why setTimeOut in this code doesn't work ? im tring to show submenus one by one , im not sure if the way is good , someone told me there is a problem in the closure

the code :

```
function changestyle(){
            var els = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
            for(var i = 0; i < els.length-1; i++)
            {

                
                const showone = function(){
                    els[i].style.display = 'block';
                    
                  };
            
                  const hideone = function(){
                    els[i].style.display = 'none';
                    
                  };
                  setTimeout(showone, 2000);
                setTimeout(hideone, 2000);
            }
            }
```

Comment: There are 0 ms between your `showone` call and your `hideone` call. [`setTimeout`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) is non-blocking. What exactly is the expected result? See [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](/q/3583724/4642212).

Comment: If you don’t use `let i = 0`, then yes, there’s a problem in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

The time for showing and hiding is colliding. You can try setTimeout(hideone, 3000);
instead of setTimeout(hideone, 2000);

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this. It may works for your case.

```
function changestyle(){
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
    for(var i = 0; i < els.length-1; i++) {
       els[i].style.display = 'block';
            
       const hideone = function(){
          els[i].style.display = 'none'; 
       };
       setTimeout(hideone, 2000);
     }
   }
```

Comment: How is this better? This has all the same problems.